# Best TimeMachine solution for macOS Sierra given current hardware?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, imac, high-sierra

I have an iMac running El Capitan (can't upgrade further) that has been hosting my TimeMachine backup for years. New MacBook Pro can't see the Time Machine volume - doesn't even see the drive connected to the iMac as an option.

I have a blank 4 TB 5.25" drive I can use for an alternate TimeMachine backup. What setup should I use for optimal outcome? Can I connect it to the iMac in a way that will make it available? Enclosure connected directly to the MBP seems far less convenient than the old method, where TimeMachine would just run whenever I was on my home network...

Comment: Should note that MBP is APFS, while all other systems are HFS+ - which likely makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy the "Server" app from the App Store ($20 I think), it will let you once again use your iMac as a network based backup destination for Macs running Time Machine on the network. You can just turn on the Backup feature in Server.app and ignore all the rest.

You can most likely do this without the server app using some command line tricks, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

The only other solution is physically plugging in the drive to each Mac, one by one. But like you said, that's not ideal.

Comment: ...so basically the feature that worked out of the box before now requires a paid app? Between this and a few really noticeable bugs in the new MBP I am seriously disappointed with the direction Apple has been heading.

Comment: Ah. Struck on a solution. Browse to server using Go -> Connect to Server and specifically use afp. Once I did that, Time Machine was able to see the disk. Weird. Used to work via Finder if I mounted the drive. Was able to inherit and associate the old backup after that. Too many negative reviews of the most recent Server app for me to even try that.

Comment: Yeah apple made SMB the default now, which isn't great since it lacks features. I didn't think you could still use Time Machine that way though, even if you manually force an AFP connection. I wonder if it's just because you're on an older version.